# Valgrind on linux: delaying start of activation

Tags: linux, valgrind, callgrind

Using

`valgrind --tool=callgrind`

on Linux

.....I would like to pass canned messages into my process.  However for the first eg 90% of the messages I would like to process as normal, with no grinding, in order to build up a map.  Then I would like to activate valgrind/callgrind only for the last 10% messages.

Is this possible?

Maybe there is a way to increment a counter in my C++ code and when it reaches a certain threshold, activate valgrind/callgrind.

Your feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. You have to use a mix of `--instr-atstart=no` along with either a `callgrind_control` or a "toggle function" (`--toggle-collect`). The later seems more applicable to your scenario. See [§6.2.2 "Limiting the range of collected events"](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#opt.toggle-collect) of the Valgrind manual for more information.